# How to troubleshoot job Queues with Beanstalk on Laravel

Tags: php, macos, laravel, queue, beanstalkd

## Background

I'm given a laravel app who's queue is configured by forge. And so I'm trying to make it run now on my localhost which is OSX

This is what I did:

[installed](http://kr.github.io/beanstalkd/download.html) beanstalk on OSX
ran beanstalk server on my console: `$ beanstalk`
ran the laravel worker command

```
$ php artisan queue:work beanstalkd --env=local --queue=default
```

I then did some actions that create jobs, but they never got processed. I used telnet as a poor man's monitor for beanstalk like so:

```
$ telnet localhost 11300
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
stats
OK 923
---
current-jobs-urgent: 0
current-jobs-ready: 3
current-jobs-reserved: 0
current-jobs-delayed: 0
current-jobs-buried: 0
cmd-put: 3
cmd-peek: 0
cmd-peek-ready: 0
cmd-peek-delayed: 0
cmd-peek-buried: 0
cmd-reserve: 0
cmd-reserve-with-timeout: 652
cmd-delete: 0
cmd-release: 0
cmd-use: 1
cmd-watch: 0
cmd-ignore: 0
cmd-bury: 0
cmd-kick: 0
cmd-touch: 0
cmd-stats: 8
cmd-stats-job: 0
cmd-stats-tube: 0
cmd-list-tubes: 0
cmd-list-tube-used: 0
cmd-list-tubes-watched: 0
cmd-pause-tube: 0
job-timeouts: 0
total-jobs: 3
max-job-size: 65535
current-tubes: 2
current-connections: 2
current-producers: 0
current-workers: 1
current-waiting: 0
total-connections: 8
pid: 56692
version: 1.10
rusage-utime: 0.010171
rusage-stime: 0.031001
uptime: 2023
binlog-oldest-index: 0
binlog-current-index: 0
binlog-records-migrated: 0
binlog-records-written: 0
binlog-max-size: 10485760
id: 3620777b4ee08cdc
```

## Question

I can see that 3 jobs are ready.. but i have no idea how to dispatch them (or for that matter, find out what jobs are exactly inside of them). What should I do?

Comment: Have you tried queue:listen?

Comment: That's laravel 5.1 syntax.. this is laravel 5.3

Answer (score 0):

You can use the beanstalk console web app https://github.com/ptrofimov/beanstalk_console. 
I would also log some info in a separated log file, to inform me about some values and details happening within the running job. Then I tail that log file while executing the queued jobs and watching the beanstalk console interface.